# Instalacion de MongoDB se congela en Windows 7

Tags: mongodb, instalacion

Estoy instalando ***mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012plus-4.2.0-signed*** ya intente varias veces, pero la instalación se congela cuando trata de instalar ***MongoDb Compass.*** 
Aclaro que al inicio de la instalación destildo la opcion de mantener el servicio activo cuando inicio mi sistema.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no trata sobre un problema de programación, tal como se establece en el [help/dont-ask]. El problema planteado es sobre configuración/instalación de un programa o servicio.

Answer (score 0):

Hace tiempo que lo instalé y creo recordar que al instalarlo conjuntamente daba problemas y me ocurría lo mismo. Creo que instalándolo por separado se podía hacer sin problemas, quitando la opción de instalar Compass y luego instalandolo después.

Prueba así, aunque ya te digo que fue hace tiempo cuando lo hice.